# Chart.js - Black bar colors in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart made with Chart.js which is working perfectly in my website by doing this:

```
<canvas id='chart-area'></canvas>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: ['13', '10', '112', '158', '37'],
                backgroundColor: ['rgb(43, 177, 0, 1)', 'rgb(174,177, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,165, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,47, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,0, 0, 1)']
            }],
            labels: ['Até R$ 50', 'R$ 50 - R$ 100', 'R$ 100 - R$ 250', 'R$ 250 - R$ 500', 'Acima de R$ 500']
        },
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var ctx = jQuery('#chart-area')[0].getContext('2d');
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    });
</script>
```

[image]

However, for mobile devices, the bar colors are all black and some of the legends are missing:

[image]

Still, when I click on any bar in a mobile device, the bars disappear.

Any advise on my code that could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

1) You mentioned that some of the labels are missing on the xAxis of the chart. In ChartJS there is an option to set `autoSkip` to false by default it's true I believe which will allow all labels on the xAxis to not be skipped.

2) As for the colors not showing up correctly on mobile, can you try to get rid of the transparency and see if it works? I ran into the same problem and I got rid of the transparency values and it worked for me. Also, you have responsive set to `false` try setting that to `true` and see if it fixes the color issue.

```
var config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: ['13', '10', '112', '158', '37'],
            backgroundColor: ['rgb(43, 177, 0, 1)', 'rgb(174,177, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,165, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,47, 0, 1)', 'rgb(255,0, 0, 1)']
        }],
        labels: ['Até R$ 50', 'R$ 50 - R$ 100', 'R$ 100 - R$ 250', 'R$ 250 - R$ 500', 'Acima de R$ 500']
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
          ticks: {
              autoSkip: false,
           }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The colors were solved by using hexadecimal notation instead of rgb with opacity and the xAxis were solved by reducing their size (it was a matter of room for them to fit).